# What is the dimension of $\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory

Consider a Hamel bases of $\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{Q}$：$\lbrace r_{i} \rbrace_{i \in I}$, then what is the cardinal of
$\lbrace r_{i} \rbrace_{i \in I}$?

I have proved that it is uncountable, so if we admit the the continuum hypothesis its cardinal must be $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$. But could we avoid the the continuum hypothesis to prove its cardinal is $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: No need for the continuum hypothesis. Over a countable field, the vector space spanned by $\aleph_\alpha$ basis vectors will contain only $\aleph_\alpha$ elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a good exercise to show that for any vector space $V$ over the rationals, any set of vectors $X$ satisfies $$\vert \langle X\rangle\vert\le\max\{\aleph_0,\vert X\vert\}$$ (here $\langle...\rangle$ is the span). So yes, regardless of whether $\mathsf{CH}$ holds we have $\dim_\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{R})=2^{\aleph_0}.$

That said, we can do even better. We can explicitly (and without the axiom of choice) construct a size-continuum linearly-independent-over-$\mathbb{Q}$ set of real numbers; see the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202/explicit-big-linearly-independent-sets), or [this old answer of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/a/282837/8133). Of course this falls short of being a Hamel basis (as any choice-free argument must), but it does lead to a proof in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that any Hamel basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ must have cardinality continuum.